# get the missing numbers between list of numbers using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

in my database I have 10 users numbers some of them have been deleted, and when I select the column at shows like this:

```
missing_user_number:
        1,
        2,
        5,
        8,
        10,
```

and I need to know if there is a script that can get the missing numbers like this, I don't want the deleted data back, I just want the missing numbers as an integrs data:

```
missing_user_number:
        3,
        4,
        6,
        7,
        9,
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific SQL can be handy.)

Comment: sql server 2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most versions of SQL, it is actually easier to get *ranges* of missing values, rather than each missing value:

```
select user_number + 1 as missing_range_start, next_user_number - 1 as missing_range_end
from (select t.*,
             lead(user_number) over (order by user_number) as next_user_number
      from t
     ) t
where user_number <> user_number + 1;
```

Note:  This only finds *internal* missing numbers, as in the example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an in-line numbers table that contains all 10 user numbers. Then `LEFT JOIN` your table to it in order to get the missing numbers:

```
SELECT t1.n AS missing_user_number
FROM (
   SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 ... SELECT 10  
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.n = t2.user_number
WHERE t2.user_number IS NULL
```